# splitting this array into 2 dimension

Tags: php, arrays

i have an array with something like this

```
  Array
(
[0] => section 1
[1] => xyz
[2] => xyz
[3] => xyz
[4] => ====================================================================================================
[5] => section 2
[6] => abc
[7] => abc
[8] => ====================================================================================================
)
```

so i would like to convert this array into a 2 dimension array with the ================== as a delimiter

possible to something like this?

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => section 1
        [1] => xyz
        [2] => xyz
        [3] => xyz
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => section 2
        [1] => abc
        [2] => abc
    )
)
```

trying to use the explode method but it seems like not returning what i really wanted

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`explode()`](http://php.net/explode) working with strings. You can do it with common [`foreach`](http://php.net/foreach)-loop:

```
$result = [];
$index  = 0;

foreach($array as $value){
    if(preg_match('/^\=+$/', $value)){
        $index++;
    } else {
        $result[$index][] = $value;
    }
}

print_r($result);
```

Example:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8');

$array = [
    1,
    2,
    'section',
    '=============',
    'test',
    'test2',
    null
];

$result = [];
$index  = 0;

foreach($array as $value){
    if(preg_match('/^\=+$/', $value)){
        $index++;
    } else {
        $result[$index][] = $value;
    }
}

print_r($result);
?>
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 2
            [2] => section
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => test
            [1] => test2
            [2] => 
        )

)
```

Comment: thanks alot, it works...seems like going a wrong way earlier.